# Choosing download location for youtube-dl python

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, youtube-dl

I'm using youtube-dl for a discord bot in python and it works fine, however it downloads the files to the root directory of the project. Since it will be downloading LOTS of videos, I would prefer for it to download to a directory inside of the root. How do I do this?

These are my current options:

```
ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'reactrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_addreacs': '0.0.0.0',  # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addreacses cause issues sometimes
    'output': r'youtube-dl'
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'before_options': '-nostdin',
    'options': '-vn'
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set an output template containing slashes in the [`outtmpl` option](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/3e4cedf9e8cd3157df2457df7274d0c842421945/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L161):

```
ytdl_format_options = {
    'outtmpl': 'somewhere/%(extractor_key)s/%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
     ...
}
```

Output templates can have *lots* of fields (including playlist IDs, license, format name/bitrates, album name & much more, depending on what the video website you're using supports). For more information, refer to the [youtube-dl documentation of output templates](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template). All fields can be used as directory or file names.